# What order types can well-ordered proper classes have?

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals, well-orders, second-order-logic

Ordinals are order types of well-ordered sets.  Proper classes can be well-ordered too, though, the most famous example being the class of all ordinals under the standard ordering.  So my question is, what order-types can well-ordered proper classes have?  If we let $\Omega$ be the order type of the ordinals, how much bigger than $\Omega$ can we go?

I’m guessing that the order types of well-ordered proper classes cannot be put in one-to-one correspondence with the class of all sets, just as the order types of well-ordered countable sets cannot be put in one-to-one correspondence with the set of natural numbers.

EDIT: I am asking my question in the context of Morse-Kelly set theory.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Well-ordered by what? What is your foundational system? NBG? MK?

Comment: @user21820 I edited my question to specify MK.  And by a well-ordered proper class I mean a proper class $X$ together with a class relation, i.e. a proper class of ordered pairs of elements of $X$, which is a well-ordering.

Comment: Ok. It's now clear.

Answer (score 6):

To make things clearer I'm going to rephrase the question as follows *(it's  not hard to translate between this question, which is asked in the ZFC context, and your question as you've phrased it)*:

> Suppose $M$ is a transitive model of ZFC. Let $\alpha_M$ be the supremum - calculated in $V$ - of the ordertypes of the definable *(-in-the-sense-of-$M$)* well-orderings of subsets *(-in-the-sense-of-$V$)* of $M$. What can we say about $\alpha_M$?

(This is closely related to [this old Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116590/what-is-omega-1ck-mathsford).)

A good first observation is the following:

> Let $N$ be the **least admissible set above $M$** - that is, $N$ is the smallest transitive model of Kripke-Platek set theory with $M\in N$. Then $\alpha_M\le N\cap Ord$.

*(I'll write "$\omega_1^{CK}(M)$" for $N\cap Ord$.)*

This is a more-mysterious-looking special case of a general fact: if $A$ is an admissible set and $S$ is a structure in $A$, then every $S$-definable well-ordering of a subset of $S$ is an element of $A$.

---

OK, now is that *sharp*? Let's especially focus on the case when $M=L_\gamma$ for some ordinal $\gamma$; in this case we have $\alpha_M$ is just the least admissible ordinal $>\gamma$, which I'll call $\omega_1^{CK}(\gamma)$, where an ordinal $\gamma$ is admissible if $L_\gamma$ is an admissible set. *(The standard notation is, sadly, "$\gamma^+$." I know, I know, ...)*

It's worth pointing out at this point that our experiences from classical computability theory are *wildly* misleading here. Specifically, we classically have that $\omega_1^{CK}$ (= the least admissible ordinal $>\omega$) is the supremum of the classically-computable ordinals. This suggests that in general we should have that $\omega_1^{CK}(\gamma)$ should be the supremum of the "$\gamma$-computable" ordinals, that is, of the ordinals which are (the ordertype of) a well-ordering of $\gamma$ which is $\Sigma_1$-definable over $L_\gamma$. *(At least, for "reasonably closed" $\gamma$ - say, admissible $\gamma$. Note that if $M\models ZFC$ then $M\cap Ord$ is trivially admissible, and indeed much more, so this isn't really a meaningful restriction in our context.)*

**This is very false in general**, however; see e.g. [this old Mathoverflow answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277343/order-type-of-alpha-computable-well-orderings/277345#277345). The takeaway from this is that **the next admissible is generally really really big** - in particular, we should be very suspicious of the upper bound above!

Indeed, the upper bound above is **generally not sharp**:

> We have $$\alpha_{L_{\omega_1}}<\omega_1^{CK}(\omega_1).$$

*(Incidentally, the ordinal $\omega_1^{CK}$ is also called "$\omega_{\omega_1+1}^{CK}$.")*

The proof is via a nice trick: if $w$ is a non-well-ordering in $L_{\omega_1}$, then there is a descending sequence through $w$ which is also in $L_{\omega_1}$ *(Mostowski absoluteness + regularity of $\omega_1$)*. This means that in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}(\omega_1)}$ we can computably tell whether a formula $\varphi$ with parameters in $L_{\omega_1}$ defines (in $L_{\omega_1}$) a well-ordering: search simultaneously for descending sequences through $\varphi^{L_{\omega_1}}$ and for isomorphisms between $\varphi^{L_{\omega_1}}$ and some ordinal. This lets us build a copy of $\alpha_{L_{\omega_1}}$ inside $L_{\omega_1^{CK}(\omega_1)}$.

---

More generally, if $M$ is a transitive model of ZFC with $M^\omega\subseteq M$, then:

- $\alpha_M<\omega_1^{CK}(M)$, and
- more generally the supremum of the $\Sigma_k$-definable well-orderings of $M$ (in the sense of $M$) has a copy which is $\Sigma_{k+1}$-definable over $M$.

In general, I suspect that both these phenomena hold for *all* models of ZFC, but I don't see it immediately.

---

So what *is* a good upper bound? Well, unfortunately there aren't really many natural ordinals below the next admissible but above all the "small $\omega_1^{CK}$ analogues." So I don't really have any good candidates.

Comment: So how does this result translate to my question, which isn’t about set models of ZFC, but about what’s actually true in the standard model of ZFC, which is a class model?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, I'm aware. Per my first line, "local" results of this type translate nicely to "global" results in the MK context - in fact, we often *gain* nuance when this happens since MK really only lets us talk about "one level up" from $V$. Essentially what the above says is that in a very strong way the collection of all classes **cannot** form an "admissible structure above $V$" - the ordinals so produceable are just too small. But the "flatness" of MK makes it hard to say more.

Comment: So is this basically a way of putting a (qualitative, if not quantitative) upper bound on the order types of well-ordered proper classes?  And if classes aren’t enough to produce an admissible structure above $V$, how many layers do we need to produce such a structure?  Second-level classes, third-level classes, omega-level classes, or what?

Comment: Also, what is the answer to my question about whether the order-types of well-ordered proper classes can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the class of all sets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "qualitative" - I'd rather say, "not (in general) sharp." Unfortunately I think one of the takeaways from the argument above is that there's not going to be a snappy description of the relevant ordinal.

Comment: Meanwhile, your additional question is difficult to answer - what sort of thing is that "one-to-one correspondence"? Is it definable, and if so, in what sense? (Note that this all becomes vastly easier to talk about in the "local" analogue - I suggest *first* attacking that and *then* moving to the "$V$-version.")

Comment: I think I’m asking about the truth value of a specific statement in the language of MK: there exists a two-place class relation $R$ and a three-place class relation $S$ such that for any fixed $x$, the two-place relation $S(x,y,z)$ is a well-ordering on the class of all $y$ such that $R(x,y)$, and such that for any class $C$ and any class well-ordering $T$ on $C$, there exists an $x$ such that the two-place relation $S(x,y,z)$ is order-isomorphic to $T$.  And I’m guessing that that statement is false.

Comment: I just posted that as a follow-up question: ‪https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564954/71829‬